# JS variable scope: pushing into an array in one function and accessing it another function

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/ujapned5/

I'm trying to make an "initializer" function that will be used to define CSS id and class names.

```
function init() {

    //our empty array for pushing
    var DivNamingPushArray = [];

    //object where we define our properties that will be used later
    var namingScheme = {
        "parentId": {
            "firstChild": "blah",
            "secondChild": "blahblah",
            "thirdChild": "blahblahblah"
        }
    }

    //loop through the namingScheme object and push into array
    for (propOne in namingScheme) {
        DivNamingPushArray.push(propOne);
        for (propTwo in namingScheme[propOne]) {
            DivNamingPushArray.push(namingScheme[propOne][propTwo])
        }
    }
}

function execute() {

    //call the "init" function
    init();

    //this cannot be called
    console.log(DivNamingPushArray);

    //however, why can this be successfully called?
    console.log(propOne);
}

execute();
```

I would really prefer to keep these functions separate, instead of including `execute` inside `init`. There are other functions that will need to call the `DivNamingPushArray` variable later on.

I am looking through the MDN documentation on variable scope but not finding a simple solution...

Comment: Please note that if you don't declare `propOne` and `propTwo` they will be global. Using strict mode would prevent these kind of potential future problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a third function to separate your logic

As for the propOne, you can see my comment in your question, just put `var` in front of it.

**[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelduch/ujapned5/3/)**

```
execute();

function init(app) {
    app.DivNamingPushArray = getNamingArray();
}

function execute() {
    var app = {};

    //call the "init" function
    init(app);

    console.log(app.DivNamingPushArray);

}

function getNamingArray() {
    //our empty array for pushing
    var DivNamingPushArray = [];

    //object where we define our properties that will be used later
    var namingScheme = {
        "parentId": {
            "firstChild": "blah",
            "secondChild": "blahblah",
            "thirdChild": "blahblahblah"
        }
    }

    //loop through the namingScheme object and push into array
    for (var propOne in namingScheme) {
        DivNamingPushArray.push(propOne);
        for (var  propTwo in namingScheme[propOne]) {
            DivNamingPushArray.push(namingScheme[propOne][propTwo])
        }
    }

    return DivNamingPushArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This will definitely come in handy as I continue to learn best OOP practices.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable without the keyword `var`, it becomes global. Add `var` before you declare the variables in `for...in` loop.

```
for (var propOne in namingScheme) {
    DivNamingPushArray.push(propOne);
    for (var propTwo in namingScheme[propOne]) {
        DivNamingPushArray.push(namingScheme[propOne][propTwo])
    }
}
```

When a variable becomes global, or part of `window`, it can be accessed anywhere. So, always use `var` to keep the variables in scope and thereby avoiding the pollution of global scope.

After you've called `init`, `propOne` and `propTwo` have become global variables and therefore can be accessed anywhere. As to `DivNamingPushArray`, declare it one-level higher, so it will be visible to other functions or try to use module pattern.

Comment: @aduch it did already, but yet, I've made it even more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use some js pattern like module to separate it:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

and the using something like observer to let function comunicate.

This is not a simple implementing solution, but you can have fun with it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `DivNamingPushArray` accessible within the scope of `execute()`, take its declaration one level upper, before `init()` declaration :

```
//Declare your array outside of your init function
var DivNamingPushArray = [];

function init() {
   //...
```

For `propOne`, see Amit Joki's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variable scoping works like this:

```
//this will not be changed in "init" function.
DivNamingPushArray = [];

//this will be changed because you don't localize your variable in init function
propone = 'value'; 

function init() {

    //this "var" declaration localizes the variable. 
    //You can do anything you want with it and 
    //the global DivNamingPushArray wont change.
    //The only way to use the global variable now is through 
    //the global object. (window.DivNamingPushArray for browsers)
    var DivNamingPushArray = [];

    // if you would have used "for (var propOne in namingScheme)",
    // the variable would have been local
    for (propOne in namingScheme) {
        // ...
    }
}
```